# R ggplot2 X axis plotted as levels

Tags: r

I cant force R to plot my my data with the x-axis in ascending order. When I plot this data, the x-axis is in the order 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, ...

```
library(ggplot2)
BradfordProteinData<-read.csv(normalizePath('data/ch3/bpa.csv'))
BPD<-BradfordProteinData[-(1),]
xx<-BPD[,1]
yy<-BPD[,3]
xx
yy
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
ggplot(BPD) + geom_point(aes(x=Hour, y=OD600))
qplot(xx,yy, geom = c("point", "smooth"))
qplot(sort(Hour, decreasing=FALSE), OD600, data = BPD, geom = c("point", "smooth"))
```

The values `xx` and `yy` are of `class(xx) # factor`. 
My SE points are too low to embed images, but here is my data as .csv

```
Hour,OD600,OD600,OD600,Average,StdDev
Hour,R1,R2,R3,Average,StdDev
1,0.037,0.040,0.031,0.036,0.003
2,0.048,0.044,0.042,0.044,0.002
3,0.097,0.091,0.093,0.093,0.002
4,0.0286,0.320,0.331,0.226,0.140
5,1.272,1.099,1.29,1.220,0.086
6,1.71,2.476,2.058,2.081,0.313
7,2.606,3.08,2.818,2.834,0.193
8,3.614,3.806,3.808,3.742,0.090
9,4.594,5.221,4.933,4.916,0.256
10,5.364,5.31,6.32,5.664,0.463
11,6.812,6.741,5.102,6.218,0.789
12,5.151,6.649,4.908,5.569,0.769
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
sort(as.numeric(Hour), decreasing=FALSE)
```

this your strings "10","11" will be treated as numeric thus sorted by numeric value and not string value